# Omitting "be" after "consider"

Tags: grammar

Let's see 2 sentences begin with "Should I consider"

> 1. Should I consider the prince’s safety **threatened** because he asked you
>      to the ball?
> 2. Should I consider him a servant?

If I make these sentences, I would make them like that,

> 3. Should I consider the prince's safety being threatened ...?
> 4. Should I consider him as (or being) a servant?

Could you please explain the grammar to me?

Comment: Will you please explain which detail of the grammar, in the four sentences, is unclear, and why?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @virolino, why is "safety threatened" correct?

Comment: @PeterFlom, how about "noun + verb past participle"?

Comment: @virolino, I got it after asking this question in a Chinese English-studying forum. It's called "Postpositional Attributive".

Comment: Thank all of you concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two sentences are fine.

Sentence 3 is, I think, grammatical but awkward and means something a little different. The "being" here makes it hypothetical. Suppose you are in the palace staff and you are drawing up plans and one thing is to figure out what to do if various things happen. You are asking if you should consider what should be done if someone threatens the prince's safety.

Sentence 4: Adding the "as" makes the sentence sound rather stilted to me, but I don't think it's ungrammatical.